# how to make label in asp.net that will accept paragraph with indention or number list?

Tags: asp.net

I have a label in my popup modal, i need to pass information from the main page sort of preview, the problem is the label wont display it as number list or paragraph.

can someone help me on this?

```
       $('#<%= txtDetails.ClientID %>').on('change', function () {
            $('span[id$="lblDecription"]').text($(this).val());
        });

        $('#<%= txtIssue.ClientID %>').on('keyup', function () {
            $('span[id$="lblSummary"]').text($(this).val());
        });

        $('#<%= txtResolutions.ClientID %>').on('change', function () {
            var resolution = $('#<%= txtResolutions.ClientID %>').val();
            $('input[id$="txtKBResolution"]').text(resolution);
        });
```

Comment: from where is the content coming from? If you can please show some code, or screenshots

Comment: i have a page which has 3 textbox, then i have a link button that displays a modal which has 3 textbox also, what i want to do is when the modal shows the value i typed, pasted on the page will be displayed in the modal. heres the code

Comment: Please edit your post and post all the code there

Comment: Why `$('input[id$="txtKBResolution"]').text(resolution);`? Instead of `.text()` call `.val()` and pass your argument...assuming that is a textbox of course...